# How to implement 1-sigmoid in Keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, gated-recurrent-unit

As I want to implement a structure which is similar to the update gate of GRU:

h<sub>t</sub> = (1-z<sub>t</sub>)h<sub>t-1</sub> + z<sub>t</sub>h<sub>t</sub>

And I am trying to implement it with these code but it doesn't work. I am sure the problem are in the following code:

```
one = K.ones(shape=(1, len, 128))
zt=Subtract([one,zt])
temp_conv2=multiply([reset_conv,zt])
output=Add([temp_conv1,temp_conv2])
```

I have the following error:

> AttributeError:'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'

I have already tried some other method such as using `Lambda` layer but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`one` is not a Keras Tensor therefore you would get that error. You can wrap this in a `Lambda` layer:

```
zt = Lambda(lambda x: Subtract([K.ones(shape=(1, len, 128)), x]))(zt)
```

Even you don't need to construct that Tensor of ones. Simply use `1-x`:

```
zt = Lambda(lambda x: 1-x)(zt)
```

It will be automatically broadcasted and the subtraction would be element-wise.